# Python: Change condition value of while loop from called module inside loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want the variable for the condition of my while loop (while repeat is True) to be changed (to repeat = False, thus not meeting the condition of the while loop) via the if statement in the action() module that is being called within the while loop itself.
Comments should explain my intentions throughout.

*Note* This is a simplified version of the larger code I am actually working. Hopefully I made it simple and clear enough to get my point across without additional confusing code as I have come across in other posts.

```
# Defining the variables

repeat = True
class monster:
    hp = 5
class fighter:
    damage = 1

# Defining my action module

def action():
   monster.hp -= fighter.damage # Monster's hp decreases by fighter's damage
   print "Monster HP is %s" % monster.hp # Print this result
   if monster.hp < 1: # Check to see if monster is dead, hp less than 1
       repeat = False # If monster is dead, stop repeating
   else:
      repeat = True # If monster is not dead, repeat attack

# Here is the while loop

while repeat is True: # Defining the condition for the while loop
   print "repeat is %r" % repeat # Here it should print repeat is True
  action() # Then call the action module

print "repeat is %r" % repeat # Here it should print repeat is False
```

Comment: No, no, no! **Never** use `if something == True` or `if something == False`. Use `if something` or `if not something`, or if you really want to check whether the value is the canonical `True` or `False` object, use `if something is True` or `if something is False`.

Comment: Juan's answer solved the question I was asking, but thank you for this information, I will update accordingly.

Comment: Explanation: In a boolean context, nonempty containers, nonzero numbers, and most other objects that don't have a zero-like value are considered true, but `== True` will report `False`. Also, for historical reasons, `1 == True`, so even if you really care whether the value is the object `True`, `==` doesn't work. You have to use `is` to check object identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare repeat as a global variable to change it from inside action(). Include this line after the def action():

```
def action():
    global repeat
```

Comment: Remember if you modify a global variable from inside a function yo have to declare it as global. If you just ad the variable there is no need to use global.